# Facebook Connect + CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, facebook

I'm trying to install Facebook Connect on my web site. When I run it locally I get this error:

> `Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_multi_init() in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\application\libraries\facebook.php on line 122`

This is the code:

```
class facebookConnection {

    // Allow multi-threading.

    private $_mch = NULL;
    private $_properties = array();

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->_mch = curl_multi_init();

        $this->_properties = array(
                'code'      => CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE,
                'time'      => CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME,
                'length'    => CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD,
                'type'      => CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your WAMP setup doesn't have Curl Multi extension. Do a phpinfo and check available extensions. Google for how to enable curl_multi on your box